# OrchestrationTrigger Cannot access a disposed object

Tags: azure-functions

I have a function where it connects to external API and because I can't have too many requests in a short period of time I'm trying to use OrchestrationTrigger. All seems to work until the last part where at the end I update the database and I get the following error:

```
Exception: DurableTask.Core.Exceptions.TaskFailureException: Activity function 'MyTrigger' failed: Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
Object name: 'BaseContext'.
```

This only happen when using DurableTask. This is my code:

*Setup.cs*

```
builder.Services.AddLogging(options => options.AddConsole());

builder.Services.AddDbContext<BaseContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

builder.Services.AddSingleton((container) =>
    {
        var context = container.GetService<BaseContext>();
        var stack = container.GetRequiredService<ILogger<StackService>>();
        return new StackService(stack, new StackConfiguration(context), null);
    });
```

*MyTrigger.cs*

```
public class MyTrigger : BaseTrigger
{
    private readonly Import import;

    public MyTrigger(BaseContext db, Library.Services.StackService stack) : base(db, "MyTrigger")
    {
        import = new Import(db, stack);
    }

    [FunctionName("MyTimeTrigger")]
    public void RunTimerTrigger([TimerTrigger("0 0 2 * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer)
    {
        if (myTimer.IsPastDue)
        {
            return;
        }

        import.Run();
    }

    [FunctionName("MyHTTPTrigger")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> RunHttpTrigger([DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient context, [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req)
    {
        ReqData data = await GetRequestBody<ReqData>(req);
        data.trigger = Triggers.HTTP;

        string instanceId = await context.StartNewAsync("MyOrchestrationTrigger", data);

        context.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);

        return HttpEmptyResponse();
    }

    [FunctionName("MyOrchestrationTrigger")]
    public async Task<bool> RunOrchestrationTrigger([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
    {
        var data = context.GetInput<ReqData>();
        return await context.CallActivityAsync<bool>("MyTrigger", data);
    }


    [FunctionName("MyTrigger")]
    public bool Run([ActivityTrigger] IDurableActivityContext inputs)
    {
        ReqData data = inputs.GetInput<ReqData>();
        return import.Run(data);
    }
}
```

What could I be missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `builder.Services.AddSingleton` to `builder.Services.AddTransient` did the trick.

https://karthiktechblog.com/c-sharp/how-to-resolve-cannot-access-a-disposed-object-in-dotnet-core-when-injecting-dbcontext